Explanation of Sentence in Godsil's "Algebraic Graph Theory"

I was hoping somebody could explain to me why the following sentence holds in the picture above: "One consequence of our next result is that the real number $\rho$ from the previous lemma is the spectral radius of $A$." The real number $\rho$ from the previous lemma is defined again in lemma 8.7.2.
I can't figure out why this is a consequence of lemma 8.7.2. I've provided definitions for terminology used in the sentence below (in case different people use different words, or perhaps the same words with different meanings).



Lemma 8.7.1. in Godsil states:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ nonnegative irreducible matrix. Then there
is a maximum real number $\rho$ such that there is a
$\rho$-subharmonic vector for $A$. Moreover, any $\rho$-subharmonic
vector $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\rho$, and all
entries of $x$ are positive.

So we know that any $\rho$-subharmonic vector is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\rho$. Now, just take $B=A$ in lemma 8.7.2. We have $|A|\leq A$ as $A$ is nonnegative, so any eigenvalue $\theta$ of $A$ has $|\theta|\leq \rho$. Thus $\rho$ is the spectral radius of $A$, as desired.
